# How to be automate deployment of a Function to AWS Azure and GCP

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, google-cloud-platform, devops, faas

I have a nodeJS function which has to be scaled up to a large extent, 
How do I deploy it to any of the cloud environments (FAAS) ?

I want a solution which is agnostic to cloud and should be opensource(I see there is serverless.com) but is there something better which I can implement myself?

I am also not for using cloudformation or something specific since I will be coupled with AWS

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that you cannot today. Each cloud has its own features that you should design to before deploying a function. The details of how to implement a function are different. Each of the vendors implements authentication and authorization differently. The entry point, libraries, dependencies, etc. are different. Anything more complex than Hello World that uses storage, database or other services will be vendor specific.

FaaS cross-platform is not a reality today. Kubernetes will probably solve parts of this problem soon but then I would switch to serverless containers instead of functions if I planned to deploy Kubernetes.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what you want to do, It's pretty easy to write applications for AzureFunctions. The idea with Azure Functions is pretty simple. You just write one or more functions, that you then trigger in various ways. It works in a way that you trigger your functions in response to various external events.

You do not need to depend on any library. Here is the **[best place](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-develop-vs)** to start

Answer (score 0):

Like you have said you have a JS script, you would require associated integration points with popular cloud services such as storage, database or potentially another serverless function in order to complete the workflow.

Essentially, you are required to create a workflow of events which allows addressing a pre-function trigger scenario, in life (i.e. what to do when the function itself is running  - e.g. logging can be one use case) and lastly, a post-function trigger scenario.

This completes the serverless function app lifecycle. All of the above i.e. pre, in life and post-use cases are cloud platform agnostic and all of them can be opensource if you wish them to be.